# Keep a process listening for intercommunication

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to start 2 processes simultaneously. One will start processing immediately and the other will wait for the trigger (and the arguments) from the first process , for it to start processing.

Following is my code:-

**Main.py**

```
packet_obj = packet(i,30,30,30,30,0)
d = multiprocessing.Process(target = workers.send_trigger_to_controller, args = (packet_obj))
d.start()

# another process should start listening. Something like whenever a trigger is send 
# from the first process, it should then start processing.
```

**Workers.py**

```
def send_trigger_to_controller(packet_obj):

    while condition:

        if condition:
            d = multiprocessing.Process(target = send_packet_to_controller, args = (sensor_id,high_low,trigger_type))
            d.start()

        elif condition:
            d = multiprocessing.Process(target = send_packet_to_controller, args = (sensor_id,high_low,trigger_type))
            d.start()

        elif condition:
            d = multiprocessing.Process(target = send_packet_to_controller, args = (sensor_id,high_low,trigger_type))
            d.start()
```

As of right now, I'm starting a new process for each condition satisfied. PS: All of these conditions are met, but at different interval of times, hence depending upon time instance, different argument values are passed.

I want to create a single process for all of this which will be listening for all of these. If any trigger is send, that process should listen and then process , rather than creating a complete new process.

**how can I do it?**

Comment: It sounds like you want the functionality of a `Queue`.  There are methods to put / get values between processes (in this case, your varied arguments).  Start a single process that you pass the Queue into, and when various conditions are met put the arguments into the Queue instead of spinning up another Process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start 2 processes and use a queue ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html ) to communicate.

Create 2 processes using multiprocessing.Process (one producer and one consumer process).
The producer is the one that start processing immediately and the consumer the one that waits until the producer process is ready.

The producer process when it finishes it puts the results of the computation to a queue.

The consumer process "listens" on the queue and when there is an item it starts processing.

Something like:

```
class ProducerProcess(Process):

    def __init__(self, q, **kwargs):
        Process.__init__(self,)
        self.q = q

    def run():
        res = do_stuff()
        q.put(res)

class ConsumerProcess(Process):

    def __init__(self, q, **kwargs):
        Process.__init__(self,)
        self.q = q

    def run():
        while True:
            args = q.get(block=True) # wait until there is an item in the queue
            do_stuff(*args) # do stuff here


q = Queue()
p1 = ProducerProcess(q, **your_args)
p2 =ConsumerProcess(q, **extra_args)
p2.start()
p1.start()
# join the processes p1.join() p2.join() or use JoinableQueue depending what you need
```